# Play Video Inside Webview

Tags: google-tv

I have created an simple application which loads the HTML page in webview(contains js,css) which has the video play. When we run the the APK file in mobile, the video runs inside the webview. But when We install the same APK inside the Google TV, and play the video , it plays in other player instead inside the webview.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "it plays in other player instead inside the webview"? WebView is not a good candidate for playing video.

Comment: It means, it doesnot embed inside the webview, when i play the video, it opens as fullscreen in other player in Google TV.

Comment: What is the format of the video?

Answer (score 0):

Google TV devices utilize what is called "Trusted Video Path" technology. The implication of this is that there is a different media playback stack on Google TV vs an Android phone or tablet. WebView on Google TV is not going to support video playback the way you want. If you are building a web application for TV that plays video then I would recommend creating an android application that launches Chrome with your site being provided in the intent extras. If you are keen on building an Android app for Google TV then the recommendation is to use a VideoView for playback of the content. There is currently no good way to mix HTML5 apps and Android apps in the same interaction space without it being a hack that wont work consistently.

Comment: Thanks Krispy, i eventually went with your suggestion and loaded the url in the chrome outside the app. But would have loved to run the embed video inside the app.

Comment: Thanks krispy, I have a similar kind of question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244867/webview-not-loading-the-url-in-google-tv Please look at it and help me