# Webview not loading the URL in Google TV

Tags: android, android-webview, google-tv

I am trying the load a URL in the webview. The page doesnt contain any Flash content. The page contains normal text, buttons.
The problem when I try to load the URL is, The UI and UX everything is distorted and looking very ugly. User cant see the page in appropriate format.
Any Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will need a lot more information for this question to be useful. What URL are you loading? What version of Android? Screen shot would help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the issue is resolved, by removing the following attributes in manifest of the application.

```
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

But I don't know why these are causing issue.