# Angular Ionic Android app HTML5 video player stuck at 00:00

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, apk, capacitor

I built an ionic tv app that hosts videos over LAN.

We just bought this new Android 11.0 TV but most of the videos are stuck at 00:00. 2 out of 10 videos would play properly.

Videos were properly encoded via handbrake using H264 codecs. It works fine on Android and Google TV (11.0) emulators and the previous TVs where it was deployed (Built using Android 10, then updated to 11). Videos can also be played on IOS devices (via another web-app) so I'm sure they are encoded properly.

If it helps, the only difference I see between my TV and emulators is that my new TV is running Android 11.0 - arm while emulators are x86.

It's really just a simple app using html5 video tags with some listeners:

```
<video *ngIf="show"
    #videoPlayer
    preload="metadata"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
    poster="./assets/images/poster.png"
    (loadedmetadata)="onMetadataLoad($event)"
    (timeupdate)="onTimeUpdate($event)"
    [src]="showSource" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: I had read something about this before, but still didn't test it by myself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16944640/2940802

Comment: It's actually the opposite for me. It was working on a google tv fine (as well as an andriod tv) previously with no problem. Now, on a new android tv, only some of the videos work.